# How to fix this error in cp?

Tags: bash, scripts, cp

```
#!/bin/bash

SrcDir=$1
DstDir=$2

#If DstDir is not exist, this creats it
if ! [ -a $DstDir ]; then
   mkdir $DstDir
fi

#Formats 
Vformat=(mp4 avi 3gp mpeg mkv wmv mov)
Iformat=(jpg jpeg png)

Year(){
   ls -l --time-style=full-iso $1 | tr -s '[:blank:]' | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort -u
}
export -f Year

Finder(){
   find $SrcDir -iname "*.$File"
}

#Make Year of File
for File in ${Vformat[@]}
do
   Finder $File
done 2>/dev/null | xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'Year {}' | xargs -I {} -n1 mkdir -p $DstDir/{}/videos

for File in ${Vformat[@]}
do
   Finder $File
done 2>/dev/null | xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'cp -r {} ${DstDir}/$(Year {})/videos'
```

```
cp: cannot creat regular file '/2023/videos': No such file or dir
```

Why ${DstDir} is not print?
My programme copies the video files in a folder with the name of the year of their last change. The year function returns the year of the last file change. So why does cp give an error at the last line of the script?

Comment: The code snippet in your question does not show that a variable `DstDir` would be set before you use it. Why do you expect `${DstDir}` to expand to a non-empty value? Please [edit] your question and add more information and the missing code parts. What input do you use and what result do you want to get?

Comment: In `bash -c 'cp -r {} ${DstDir}/$(Year {})/videos'`, `$DstDir` is expanded by the new `bash` shell - but (unlike the function `Year`) you didn't export it

Comment: ... however I urge you to explain your end goal, so that we can suggest alternative ways to approach it

Comment: My programme copies the video files in a folder with the name of the year of their last change. The year function returns the year of the last file change. So why does cp give an error at the last line of the script?

Comment: Because you have spaces inside the command.  Assuming the file/directory is named FUDGE, then within the single quotes you end up with this command verbatim that is processed via Bash:  `cp -r FUDGE DSTDIR/YEAR FUDGE/videos`.  The space between YEAR and FUDGE in my example needs to be escaped.  Otherwise it's seen as an extra argument to `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

> In bash -c 'cp -r {} ${DstDir}/$(Year {})/videos', $DstDir is expanded by the new bash shell - but (unlike the function Year) you didn't export it –
> steeldriver

I must just export $DstDir.
I'm so sorry. I'm new.